# Trouble with query in Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables called Live and certified. Some columns exist in both tables, and some columns exist in only one table. Both tables have a field called "macAddress". Most of these macAddress values overlap in the two tables, but there are a few records that only exist in one table.

I would like a way to find all of the rows with a macAddress from the Live table when that macAddress does not exist in the certified table.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT Live.*
FROM Live
WHERE macAddress NOT IN
(SELECT macAddress FROM certified);
```

I also tried a left outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Live.*
FROM Live LEFT OUTER JOIN certified ON Live.macAddress = certified.macAddress
WHERE certified.macAddress IS NULL;
```

With both of these queries, I only got the column titles, but no records from the Live table.

Comment: Well I feel silly now - I tried the query with the opposite tables (looking for records in certified that were not included in Live) and it worked. There must not be any records to show for the query I tried before. Thanks for your response

Comment: OK.  Meanwhile I submitted an answer which assumed there are `Live.macAddress` which don't exist in `certified`.  Although it's no help for you, I'll leave it in case it can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I examined this query in Access 2007 with the sample data from `Live` and `certified` included below.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Live.*
FROM
    Live
    LEFT OUTER JOIN certified
    ON Live.macAddress = certified.macAddress
WHERE certified.macAddress IS NULL;
```

The query gives me this result set, which is what I think you're asking for.

```sql
macAddress        some_text
00-0C-29-80-BA-A3 bar
```

Table `Live`:

```sql
macAddress        some_text
00-0C-29-80-BA-A3 bar
38-60-77-77-D0-D4 foo
```

Table `certified`:

```sql
macAddress
38-60-77-77-D0-D4
```

Assuming you have verified there are `Live.macAddress` values which are not present in `certified`, but those are not returned by the same query with your data, perhaps you have `macAddress` indexed and the index is corrupted.  In that situation, you could have `Live.macAddress` values which exist in the table, but are not found in the index ... they are either garbled or missing altogether.  So when the db engine uses the index to retrieve rows from `Live`, those without `macAddress` values in the index will not be considered.

You can test whether this is the cause of the problem by ...

1. Run Compact & Repair on the database.  Then try the query again.
2. If the first suggestion didn't resolve the problem, drop any indexes based on `macAddress` and try the query again.

Also you should make a backup copy of the db file before either of those steps, just in case something goes wrong.

Index corruption has been rare in my experience with Access databases, but it can happen.  Compact & Repair has always cured it for me.  Whether or not you're trying to fix corruption, routine Compact is a useful practice.  One of the side benefits is it updates database statistics so the db engine has the latest and best information to use when deciding how to process your queries.  And with Access versions since 2000, running Compact automatically triggers Repair when Access spots a data problem.